# Make WebStorm recompile single SCSS file when any SCSS file in folder changes

Tags: sass, webstorm

I'm working on a project that my colleagues are also working on, they're working on it in Atom and they have Atom set up so that it works like this:

There's a folder, `css`, and in that folder is the main file, `custom.scss`, which imports all other scss files and is compiled in `custom.min.css` and `custom.min.css.map`. There are also subfolders with more scss files. Any time any scss file changes in `css` or any of its subfolders, `custom.scss` recompiles, but no other scss file recompiles.

Using WebStorm's SCSS File Watcher, can I do this?

My first attempt was to change the `scope` in the watcher settings, to just watching `custom.scss`, and that kinda works, but I have to change `custom.scss` every time I want it recompiled, instead of it recompiling when I change any of the other scss files as well.

My intuition is that I should have the scope set to watching all scss files in the css directory, recursively, and that I should change the `Arguments` setting in the file watcher to explicitly say `compile custom.scss into custom.min.css` but I'm not quite sure how to do that

Comment: actually... I think it already works. I've been being silly

Answer (score 1):

The key setting here is 'Track only root files' -- when that's not set, it tries to compile all watched scss files as they are saved individually, but when it is set, it only compiles a file if it is NOT marked as an include in another file.

Set the scope to watch changes on all scss files: `file:assets/css/*.scss`

Click 'Track only root files'

Change the arguments to `$FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css --style compressed` so that it minifies

Now, when you save a file included in custom.scss, it recompiles only custom.scss (and other root files) into `custom.min.css` and `custom.min.css.map`